# Emulator loading forever

Tags: android, android-studio, android-virtual-device

Whenever I am hitting run on my application, the emulator will open up, but will be stuck on the turning on screen, I have tried several AVDs and nothing will start, everything is stuck on the turning on screen of android.

Things I have tried:

Clean & Rebuild Project

Update Android Studio

Update Gradle

Sadly, nothing helped, and I'm not even sure the problem is there since, the problem isn't within the app, it is simply not even turning the emulator on to the point where I can see it's apps, the main screen, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, both of my AVDs were corrupted, and I had to create a new AVD with default values, and it finally worked.